# Android - Canvas drawLine inside ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-canvas

I've one ImageView in which I want to draw a Line. I've done the follow:

```
mImagenCampo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen_campo);
```

`crearPunto(mArea9M, mPaloIzq,v.getWidth(), mPaloIzq,Color.WHITE);`

And the function is:

```
private void crearPunto(float x, float y, float xend, float yend, int color) {

    BitmapDrawable bmpDraw = (BitmapDrawable) mImagenCampo.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = bmpDraw.getBitmap().copy(Config.RGB_565, true);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color);
    c.drawLine(x, y, xend, yend, p);
    mImagenCampo.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}
```

My problem is that the line is drawn but It doesn't get the rights coordinates. It is drawn smaller than It should be.

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to say that *mImagenCampo* is an ImageView

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void crearPunto(float x, float y, float xend, float yend, int color) {

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImagenCampo.getWidth(), mImagenCampo.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    c = new Canvas(bmp);
        mImagenCampo.draw(c);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color);
    c.drawLine(x, y, xend, yend, p);
    mImagenCampo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```