# Android Circle appearing lower than expected in imageview

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview, touch-event

I have been trying to draw a circle inside ImageView as soon as Touch Event Happens, at the position of Touch. I have worked out some examples including [Android - Canvas drawLine inside ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445161/android-canvas-drawline-inside-imageview). 
My problem is that, the circle is appearing approx. 117px lower than the point of touch.
My Code -

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        Canvas c;
        Paint p;
        ImageView v;
        Bitmap bm;

    v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),v.getHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
    c = new Canvas(bm);
    p = new Paint();        
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);        
    float x = event.getX(); float y = event.getY();
    c.drawCircle(x, y, 20, p);      

    v.setImageBitmap(bm);

    return true;
}
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_SOwlrEMpB9Z1JtVndhQlFxMG8/edit?usp=sharing) is the screen shot of the AVD (I have tested it on real device also). I have no idea what is going wrong or what basic fact I am missing.
    Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're overriding the Activity's onTouchEvent? If so, positioning will be relative to it's view rather than the image view. You'll have to account for the position of the image view and translate accordingly.

```
int relPosX = event.getX() - getLeft();
int relPoxY = event.getY() - getTop();
```

Comment: Yes, I am overriding main Activity's onTouchEvent. But I checked by passing c.drawCircle(0,0,20,p). Its correctly drawing to the top-left corner.

Comment: What is the top/left of R.id.image1? My guess is, the top is 117px.

Comment: @Bond - If you want to draw to the ImageView only if you click within the ImageView , i suggest moving your onTouchEvent into an extended ImageView. Otherwise, you'll have to translate the touch event coordinates into the ImageView coordinates like Berdon is saying.

Comment: yeah... But then how's circle(0,0) is drawing correctly to top-left corner ??

Comment: Because event.getY() is returning the absolute position (based on the activity's view). If you use that to do drawing on the ImageView you're effectively doing c.drawCircle(x, v.getTop() + relativePositionY, 20, p); You need to translate your activity view's coordinate to your ImageView's. Ie. event.getX() - getLeft() and event.getY() - getTop().

Comment: ok @Berdon thanks again for providing exact solution. Otherwise I would have to write lot of code again :)