# Android ImageView drawing objects

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have this Android program in which I want to display a `Rectangle` within the `ImageView` of the parent layout. The components are set on this hierarchy and following the layout listed below. The code to display the rectangle are also indicated below:

- LinearLayout [Vertical]
  - Spinner

    ImageView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_item" />    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CODE:

```
public class MainActivty extends Activity {

    private Display     display;
    private Spinner     spinMap;
    private ImageView   imageMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initailize();
    }
    private void initailize() {
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        spinMap = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinMap);
        imageMap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageMap);
        imageMap.draw(drawMap());
    }
    private Canvas drawMap() {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565));
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, paint);
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the application, the `Rectangle` don't get display. How can I display the `Rectangle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you [Android - Canvas drawLine inside ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445161/android-canvas-drawline-inside-imageview)

You should create bitmap with a rectangle and then feed it to ImageView

Comment: Thanks. Will I still follow the same code structure if I am going to thread the `ImageView` for events/listeners?