# Android Studio ImageView onDraw

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to draw on an Imageview using an onDraw handler.
I found the following example where a diagonal line is drawn across the ImageView (created with Eclipse):

```
package de.carpelibrum.grafik;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZeichnenView extends ImageView {
    public ZeichnenView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint pinsel = new Paint();
        pinsel.setColor(Color.rgb(64, 64, 255));
        pinsel.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), pinsel);
    }
}
```

I imported the corresponding project into Android Studio and it worked.

Now, when I want to create a similar sample project in Android Studio, I would start with designing the layout by manually placing an ImageView on the screen.
My question: how do I implement an onDraw handler that draws on this ImageView?

Regards,
Kyriakos.

Answer (score 0):

You could either make the `ImageView` programmatically, or within a layout. This answer has been developed from [Android - Canvas drawLine inside ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445161/android-canvas-drawline-inside-imageview)

Programmatically would look something like this:

```
ImageView imageView;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setId("lineImage");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParam params = (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(imageView);
        DrawOnImage(positionx, positiony, width, height, Color.BLACK);

}

private void DrawOnImage(float x, float y, float xend, float yend, int color) {

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        imageView.draw(canvas);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawLine(x, y, xend, yend, p);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

A layout based approach would look something like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lineImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_src"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and within your `Activity` you would do something similar to the top but instead of creating your `View` you would just find it within your `resources -> layout` directory.

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lineImage);
          DrawOnImage(positionx, positiony, width, height, Color.BLACK);
     }
```

Note: this code hasn't been tested.